# Rewrite on htaccess with a few variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problem with good configuration of rewrite in htaccess.

I have 4 variables:

```
$lang,
$page,
$bookmarkTitle,
$title.
```

I would like to get link like this:

1. domain/$page.html
2. domain/$lang/
3. domain/$lang/$page.html
4. domain/$page/$bookmarkTitle.html
5. domain/$lang/$page/$bookmarkTitle.html
6. domain/$page/$bookmarkTitle/$title.html
7. domain/$lang/$page/$bookmarkTitle/$title.html

Problem is with 3 and 4, or 5 and 6 because I don't know how to check which variable should open

```
#Linki

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

#Pojedyncza Oferta

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&title=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&title=$3 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2 [L]
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work property.

EDIT

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#CMS

#CMS pojedycznych ofert - jezyki
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*)/dodaj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&Add=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*)/edytuj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&Edit=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*)/usun/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&Delete=$4 [L]

#CMS zakładek - jezyki
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/dodaj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&Add=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/edytuj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&Edit=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/usun/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&Delete=$3 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria - jezyki
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3 [L]

#Linki - jezyki
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

#CMS pojedycznych ofert
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/(.*)/dodaj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&Add=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/(.*)/edytuj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&Edit=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/(.*)/usun/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&Delete=$3 [L]

#CMS zakładek
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/dodaj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&Add=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/edytuj/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&Edit=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/usun/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&Delete=$2 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*)/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2 [L]

#Linki
RewriteRule ^CMS/([a-zA-Z]{2})/$ CMS/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^CMS/(.*).html$ CMS/index.php?page=$1 [L]


#STRONA

#Pojedyncza Oferta - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&title=$4 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3 [L]

#Linki - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

#Pojedyncza Oferta
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&title=$3 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2 [L]

#Linki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

########## Start – Dostęp tylko z określonego adresu IP
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 77.253.2.83
Allow from 93.105.11.2
########## Koniec – Dostęp tylko z określonego adresu IP
```

Comment: Your rules are overlapping. You are using the same regex patterns for different links. It's always going to match the first one it finds. You need to fix how you want your links to be and they need to be different.

Comment: I edited my post, now you can see how I fix my problem.